# Computer Vision: Removing noise from an image

Tags: python, computer-vision

I need to delete the noise from this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5jJv.png). My problem is that I need a neat contour without all the lines like in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lD7Qh.png).

Do you have any suggestions how to do that using python?

Comment: To clarify, you want all the features other than the box removed?

Comment: I want only the box and the axes to stay in the picture.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your example images, I suppose you are looking for an image processing algorithm that finds the edges of your image (in your case, the border lines of the ground plan).

Have a look the [Canny edge detection algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canny_edge_detector) which might be a well-suited for this task. A tutorial with an example implementation in python can be found [here](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_canny/py_canny.html).

Comment: it's not possible to do this with canny because it considers the lines inside the box edges too ...